# Omitting "that" in "such that"

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can I omit *that* in the following sentences?

> 1. The weather is **such that** we can only stay in air-conditioned places.
> 2. The difference is **such that** all will perceive it.

Comment: Two examples from McMillan Dictionary to justify the correctness of these sentences. Their relationship was

Answer (score 2):

***Such that*** is a special construction in which **that** cannot be omitted. And it's not a determiner since it doesn't take up the determiner slot in an NP and indeed doesn't belong to an NP at all.
(NP = Noun Phrase)

> When the adjective *such* is used predicatively the content clause
>   generally follows immediately, but it does not have to:
>
> i) His circumstances were *such that* he could rarely afford a
>   restaurant meal.
>
> ii) *Such* is the mystique of planning *that* people expect that fulfilment
>   of the plan will follow automatically upon its announcement.
>
> iii) The angle of attack was *such* on take-off *that* several passengers
>   reported hearing the fuselage scrape the runway. (CGEL, p.968)

Comment: @snailplane Okay.Thanks for pointing it out. I edited and improved my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The words *such* and *that* when used together are indicative of a particular situation, behaviour or action with its resultant effect. It is not possible to omit *that* in the provided sentences where it has been used as a pronoun (Macmillan dictionary). We usually leave out *that* in sentences (in spoken & informal English) when it is used as a conjunction or when it is used as a pronoun as the object of a verb. The sentences mentioned are correct. I cite the following two examples from Macmillan Dictionary to justify their correctness, which are like the sentences asked.

> Their relationship was such that they spent every possible minute together.
>
> Their confidence was such that they spent $ 200,000 on TV advertising for their 
>     first album.